# jQuery Loading Too Slowly with Image src attr() Usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an eCommerce store and I've written a small piece of jQuery to change the SRC the logo for the home page only. The issue is that when I load the page I can see the incorrect logo load before the new SRC is applied. I have recorded the issue here:

https://app.hyfy.io/v/abmoLf1Q35/?p=1

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (top.location.pathname === '/') {
            jQuery(".logo img").attr("src", "newsrc.png");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Would I be correct in saying that for the jQuery to work the logo needs to have loaded first, which is why this is an issue?

Either way, could anybody advise if it's possible to have the jQuery take priority or suggest a better way of achieving what I need to here?

I appreciate the time taken to respond, thank you very much.

Comment: It is because your jquery is only running once the document is done loading, which means your old logo is already displayed before your script runs to replace it.

Comment: I understand there isn't an alternative though, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jquery would need to target an existing element to affect it.

in other words, the logic goes:
 1. load image asset
 2. alter source via jquery

if you have access to the css, you can put a display none on the .logo then when jquery alters the source, add a display:block via .css

```
<style>
    .logo img{
       display:none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (top.location.pathname === '/') {
            jQuery(".logo").css('display', 'block').find('img').attr("src", "newsrc.png");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: replace block with inline if your image needs to be inline

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this now. Am I right in saying it would show no logo before showing any logo? Even so, it's better than showing an incorrect logo first.

Comment: yes. it should show no logo, then pop in with the correct one

Comment: I've just thought, wouldn't this hide the logo completely for other pages? If so should I add another script for where the top.location.pathname != '/' to add the block CSS also?

Comment: if you inline the style alongside the script, it should only appear on the page you put it on.

Comment: If you add to the css, you'll also need the js, you can do this with a 'site.js' if you have one rather tha in the page - but do you want a different logo on other pages?